# Linq To Sql Join with multiple conditions and table

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

how could i convert this sql to Linq to sql

```
SELECT   v.Id, c.Id, bt.*
FROM BankTransaction bt
LEFT OUTER JOIN Customer c ON (bt.ObjectId = c.Id And bt.TransactionForObjectId = 1)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Vendor v ON (bt.ObjectId = v.Id And bt.TransactionForObjectId = 2)
LEFT OUTER JOIN AccountTitle ac ON (bt.ObjectId = ac.Id And bt.TransactionForObjectId = 3)
```

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: i am trying different linq to sql queries but didn't get the results

Comment: @Charlieface check my answer that i am trying so far.

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you. More specifically, `join c in Customer on new { bt.ObjectId, bt.TransactionForObjectId } equals new { ObjectId = c.Id, TransactionForObjectId = 1 } into cj from c in cj.DefaultIfEmpty()`

Comment: @NetMage No it's not.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i am trying so far

```
var tran = await (
                        from bankTrans in InventoryContext.BankTransaction.Where(x => x.BankId == bank.Id && x.Date <= BankTransaction.Date)
                        from ven in InventoryContext.Vendor.Where(x => bankTrans.ObjectId == x.Id && bankTrans.TransactionForObjectId == (int)TransactionFor.Vendor)
                        .DefaultIfEmpty()
                        from cus in InventoryContext.Customer.Where(x => bankTrans.ObjectId == x.Id && bankTrans.TransactionForObjectId == (int)TransactionFor.Customer)
                        .DefaultIfEmpty()
                        from other in InventoryContext.AccountTitle.Where(x => bankTrans.ObjectId == x.Id && bankTrans.TransactionForObjectId == (int)TransactionFor.Other)
                        .DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new
                        { bankTrans, ven, cus, other, cash }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: And what result do you get? You have extra filters here that are not in the SQL version `Where(x => x.BankId == bank.Id && x.Date <= BankTransaction.Date)`

Comment: @Charlieface let's i have tried this without the where clause but didn't get the desired result.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv return null.